# Using balltree to return nearest distance, however, only one specific location is chosen

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor, haversine

I have 460 points( or coordinates ) and i'm trying to find the nearest fault (total 7827 faults) 
The below code is just for getting the data (you can ignore this part)

```
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point
import pandas as pd

fd=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/DELL/faultdata.csv')
temp=fd.drop(['Fault data'],axis=1).dropna()
points1=temp.apply(lambda row: Point(row.Lat,row.Long),axis=1)
faults=gpd.GeoDataFrame(temp,crs={'init' :'epsg:4326'},geometry=points1)


aos=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/DELL/area.csv')
#HAVERSINE REUQIRES lat,long not long,lat
points2=aos.apply(lambda row: Point(row.latitude,row.longitude),axis=1)
areaofstudy=gpd.GeoDataFrame(aos,crs={'init':'epsg:4326'},geometry=points2)
areaofstudy=areaofstudy.drop(['year', 'month', 'day', 'depth','hour', 'minute'],axis=1)
```

Now using sklearn:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree
import numpy as np

def get_nearest(source,candidates,k_neighbors=1):
    tree=BallTree(candidates,leaf_size=15,metric='haversine')

    distances,indices=tree.query(source,k=1)


    distances=distances.transpose()
    indices=indices.transpose()

    print(indices) #THIS OUTPUTS  6526 REPEATEDLY 
    closest_point=indices[0]
    closest_dist=distances[0]

    return (closest_point,closest_dist)

def nearest_neighbhor(left_gdf,right_gdf,return_dist=False):

    left_geom_col=left_gdf.geometry.name
    right_geom_col=right_gdf.geometry.name

    right=right_gdf.copy().reset_index(drop=True)

    #Parse coordinates from points and insert into arrays as radians
    left_radians=np.array(left_gdf[left_geom_col].apply(lambda geom: (geom.x*np.pi/180,geom.y*np.pi/180)).to_list())
    right_radians=np.array(right_gdf[right_geom_col].apply(lambda geom: (geom.x*np.pi/180,geom.y*np.pi/180)).to_list())
    #print('lr',len(left_radians),'rr',len(right_radians))
    closest,dist=get_nearest(source=left_radians,candidates=right_radians)

    closest_points=right.loc[closest]
    closest_points=closest_points.reset_index(drop=True)

    if return_dist:
        #radians to meters
        earth_radius=6371000
        closest_points['distance']=dist*earth_radius

    return closest_points

closest_stops=nearest_neighbhor(areaofstudy,faults,return_dist=True)

closest_stops = closest_stops.rename(columns={'geometry': 'closest_stop_geom'})
areaofstudy = areaofstudy.join(closest_stops)
```

The output for ->  print(closest_stops.head())

```
     Lat     Long          closest_stop_geom     distance
0  19.373  73.5011  POINT (19.37300 73.50110)  7192.069355
1  19.373  73.5011  POINT (19.37300 73.50110)  7177.000108
2  19.373  73.5011  POINT (19.37300 73.50110)  7153.615651
3  19.373  73.5011  POINT (19.37300 73.50110)  7185.082612
4  19.373  73.5011  POINT (19.37300 73.50110)  7199.574475
```

On checking, I understood that the distance of each point in the area of study file to the index 6265 [lat:19.373  long:73.5011 ] of fault data is calculated because the output of print(indices) displays a list which contains 6265 repeatedly.

I want to find the closest fault for EACH point, so naturally it has to be a different value.